# Render pages like IE8, 9, 10, Firefox and Chrome as images automatically

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, web

I have a task to compare a webpage's layout in different IE version and browsers.
Now, I need to check the difference by my eyes.

So I think if there are some tools can auto render the webpages in different mode and save as images, so that I can use some image tools to compare those images to get the difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many sites that can do that automatically for you. Two that come to mind are [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api) and [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/features).

Comment: Did you end up using one of these, or something else? Curious what you thought was the best out there currently.